# Grails 2.5.1: use grails command-line tasks from binary plugin in lib folder

Tags: grails, plugins

In Grails 2.5.1, is it possible to use grails command-line tasks from a binary plugin in the lib folder?

I had to modify an existing third-party plugin to get it to work properly.

I put the jar generated by the following command in my project's lib directory:

```
grails package-plugin --binary
```

When my project runs, it correctly uses my modified version of the plugin.

At build time, however, I need to run a Grails task on the command line that was provided by the plugin, but, using the binary plugin, the task does not appear to be available.

e.g., if the task was `abc`, when using the real plugin being referenced in the `plugins` section of `BuildConfig.groovy`, then I could run:

```
grails abc
```

Using the binary plugin in the lib folder, however, results in the task not being available from the command line.

Also, the original plugin hooked into `grails war` to include extra steps in the build process without changing the command line.  These hooks no longer run with the binary plugin.  Is there any way to reinstate the hooks for the binary plugin?

Thanks.